# No component factory found for undefined. but did add to @NgModule.entryComponents

Tags: angular, plunker

I am getting the following error in Console of Plunker:

No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

But I did add the component (SecondComp) to entryComponents in @NgModule. Please take a look at this plnkr and let me know, why am I getting this error?

https://plnkr.co/edit/BM3NMR?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FirstComp} from './first.component'
import {SecondComp} from './second.component'
import {InjService} from './inj.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <first-comp></first-comp>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  providers: [ InjService ],
  declarations: [ App, FirstComp, SecondComp ],
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  entryComponents: [ SecondComp ],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hey man, what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to inject SecondComp into FirstComp and display it in the placeholder for FirstComp in app.ts.

Comment: Cool. I've done something recently that's kind of similar. I got it working in the plunker without the service. Might help.
https://plnkr.co/edit/XwBmRNZ7ksV9xuA90VpL?p=preview

Comment: I'll have a tinker with the service in a bit when I get 5. But that might help for now.

Comment: Ok cool, I see that. So what's the deal with using the service? Is it not valid to do it that way in Angular or is this a Plunker issue? I ask because using the services for this would be cool to decouple the work from the component.

Comment: I never really tried with the service before. I basically have a generic data table where you can load custom components into a particular column's cells instead of just Data.
I mean it's only 2 lines, a constructor injection and a viewchild.
Without knowing the ultimate end goal that's my best guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple spelling problem in your `inj.service.ts`. You spelt `SecondComp` as `SecondComponent`. Changing `SecondComponent` to `SecondComp` fixed the issue, as well as uncommenting the lines in your `addDynamicComponent` method.

`inj.service.ts`:

<sub>Before</sub>

```ts
import {SecondComponent} from './second.component' // <- Over here

// ...

addDynamicComponent() {
  const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SecondComp)
//  const component = factory.create(this.rootViewContainer.parentInjector)
//  this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView)
}
```

<sub>After</sub>

```ts
import {SecondComp} from './second.component' // <- Over here

// ...

addDynamicComponent() {
  const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SecondComp)
  const component = factory.create(this.rootViewContainer.parentInjector)
  this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView)
}
```

[Updated Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PlZDVOJi6rGiuZll6WH2?p=preview)

Comment: Wow. I'm gonna blame my blocked sinuses for missing this haha.
Good Spot!

Comment: Thank you both! really valuable to have people to bounce off of. Really appreciate the responses. Angular is a little tougher, JAVA would have flagged those misspellings a little easier, have to pay closer attention. Thanks again!

Comment: I up-voted but have less than a 15 reputation at the moment.

Comment: @user2906774 By the way, you can click on the tick underneath the downvote button to mark this answer as accepted. :)